# ¿Como configurar spring boot para iniciar sesión con Google?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, oauth2

Buenas espero que se encuentren bien, mi problema es que quiero configurar spring boot para iniciar sesión con Google además de la forma básica que es password y correo electrónico.

La tecnología que uso de frontend es ReactJS, logré obtener el token que envía google cuando inicias sesión pero no se si sirve de algo para el backend o si tengo que enviarlo y validarlo allí. La forma básica que tiene es el frontend envía las credenciales (email y password) y luego se valida en el backend y se emite un JWT.

Por otro lado encontré que existe OAuth2 que permite esto pero no logro configurarlo, siempre encuentro información obsoleta y no logro avanzar, sin mencionar que tiene OAuth2-client, OAuth2-resource-server y OAuth-authentication-server.

Les agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Si hay alguna forma mas sencilla de hacer esto, incluso si hay una forma sin OAuth2, me dicen por favor, ya me siento frustrado de no encontrar una forma clara.

Comment: una forma fácil es con firebase, pero la auth no la va a hacer spring, solo va a validar el token para saber si el user está o no autorizado en las posteriors requests. La auth la resolves "client side" y con el token te vas a tu server de spring boot